# Is there a more elegant way to turn this array to a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

So I have a nested array and I want to convert it into a hash such that a common key points to an array of values.  Here is what I have:

```
 b=[[6, "Jet"], [0, "Fuel"], [0, "Engine"]]
 c={}
 b.map { |x| c[x[0]] ||= []; c[x[0]] << x[1] }

 => {6=>["Jet"], 0=>["Fuel", "Engine"]}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The map can be modified as follows. Not much different, but no `;`.

```
b.map { |x| (c[x[0]] ||= []) << x[1] }
```

Note: `each` is more suited here.

Comment: Nice! you can also do `b.map { |k, v| (c[k] ||= []) << v }`.

Comment: @w0lf Yes! That's more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is more idiomatic, but I find it more readable to use [the Hash constructor that takes a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new):

```
c = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
b.each { |k, v| c[k] << v }
```

The result is stored in `c` ([test](http://ideone.com/stB72t)).